# What is a commonly used, easily identified icon for 'frequently ordered'

Tags: icons

I am currently designing an app for ordering food. The user is being shown suggestions according which include his favourites, frequently ordered, popular nearby etc. while the favourites and popular nearby fields have commonly identifiable icons, i can't think of one for frequently ordered.

**edit:**
currently used icons (the relevant ones):
heart - favourite, flame - trending, clock - delivery time, circling arrows - reorder
also, i'm going to be writing the text 'frequently ordered' along with the icon, so the icon doesn't have to be very recognizable but i can't not use an icon since it would break the uniformity as all the other fields have an icon

Comment: I think you mean "ordered by frequency" or "ordered by occurrence". I have no metaphor at hand - still looking.

Comment: @virtualnobi no. i wanted to use an icon for indicating an object which a user has frequently visited but not added to his favourites (heart icon)

Comment: So you're looking for "frequently visited"?

Comment: yes. that does come closest to what i'm trying to implement

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have both 'favourites' and 'frequently ordered' as separate items? The items I frequently order at a restaurant are my favourites, that's why I order then frequently :)

Answer (score 1):

A related formulation for "frequently ordered" might be "recurring". There are many icons that convey the notion of recurring orders, for some inspiration you could try [here](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1341&bih=865&q=recurring&oq=recurring&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1090.2373.0.2596.9.7.0.2.2.0.85.510.7.7.0....0...1ac.1.44.img..0.9.518.vb1BzjzgwBw#q=recurring%20icon&revid=94633660&tbm=isch).

Alternatively, the reuse of a history icon with the textual label "frequently ordered" might work as well: some samples are [here](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1341&bih=865&q=history%20icon&oq=history%20icon&gs_l=img.3..0l6j0i5l4.860.2203.0.2374.12.12.0.0.0.0.154.1171.5j7.12.0....0...1ac.1.44.img..2.10.913.M3Do-RlUvdo).

The circling arrows seem to be a common theme to these two.

If circling arrows are off limits because they have already been used, how about an icon with several smiley faces? The smiley face would invoke the pleasurable experience of the past order, and the fact there are several of them invokes the "frequent" aspect of this pleasurable experience. I'm sure this is NOT a commonly used icon, but I think it could be easily identified..

Comment: the circling arrows are being used in the CTA button for 're-order' in the current version of the app and that seems like a logical usage to me

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the "frequency" which is important for choosing an icon, it is the idea beyond.
The idea here is "hey, if everybody want these, you should too"

i suggest you to focus on this idea :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn13Ft.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: this is unhelpful for this example, where the desired frequency is the individual user's frequency not a global frequency, so 'famous' or 'most wanted' do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarking or favouriting an item is a manual action, whereas 'frequently visited' is something automatically calculated for you, so there is real value in both together.

My best suggestion here would be to try and shuffle your icons around to create the combination which makes the most sense for your users.

**Example 1:**

If you currently use 'heart' for favourite, consider using 'star' or 'bookmark' instead - both are conventional.

If you use star, then it could be that the user rates the item e.g. out of 5.

This would then free up 'heart' to represent 'frequently ordered'.

**Example 2:**

If you use a ['history'](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Ahistory%3A) icon elsewhere, e.g. for 'recently ordered', consider using a 'calendar/date' type icon for that instead. This would free up 'history' to represent 'frequently ordered'.

**Example 3:**

If you use a 'flame' for trending, consider using a trending chart line icon instead, [like this](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Atrending_up%3A). This would free up 'flame', although this makes less sense for favouriting than 'heart', 'star', 'bookmark' or even 'like'.